# NextJs 13 app first render is very slow on EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-ec2, next.js, next.js13

I have deployed my NextJS 13.4 app in AWS EC2 instance which have a ram of 2 Gb. I understand that in development mode nextjs makes the build and shows the result which might slow down loading of the page. But it takes almost 20 sec to load first time.

Below is my code for RootLayout, an entry point for my website which contains dynamic data coming from api.

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  let token = cookies().get("byg_tk");
  let cookie =
    cookies().get("Device_id")?.value || headers().get("Device_id") || uuidv4();

  const categories = await getCategory(
    { page: 1, limit: 1000000 },
    token,
    cookie
  );

  const product = await getProduct(
    {
      page: 1,
      limit: 100000,
    },
    token,
    cookie
  );
  const cartList = await getCartList({}, token, cookie);
  const contact_us = await getContactUs({}, token, cookie);
  const contact_number = await getContactNumber({}, token, cookie);
  let searchProducts = await getProductBySearch({}, token, cookie);
  let coupons = await getCoupons({}, token, cookie);
  let userdetails = await getUser({}, token, cookie);
  const recent = await getRecentViews({}, token, cookie);
  let cartDetails = {
    couponDiscount: 0,
    cod_price: 0,
  };

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <GoogleAnalytics GA_TRACKING_ID={GA_TRACKING_ID} />
      <Script
        id="bookyourgiftSchema"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
           __html: JSON.stringify(byg_schema(), null, "\t"),
        }}
      />
      <Script
        id="bookyourgiftSocialSchema"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: JSON.stringify(byg_social_schema(), null, "\t"),
        }}
      />
      <body>
        <Providers
          data={{
            coupons,
            categories,
            product,
            cartList,
            searchProducts,
            userdetails,
            contact_us,
            contact_number,
            cartDetails,
            recent,
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I tried removing the unused dependency, split the code as small as I can but still the first render is always very slow. I know that the server plays a great role to give back the required html with the data. But still, with a single project in the EC2 instance, this should not be that much of a deal.

Below is the screenshot of the network tab filtered on the basis of size.

[network tab result for first render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYDsQ.png)

What are the aspect affecting the first render to be that slow ? How can I optimise to get first render instantly ?

I have tried removing all the unused dependency, CSS and other heavy dependency affecting the size of the build. I am quite not sure on how to reduce the JS file so I can't say I did that. I also used cache method from react to cache the api calls. But that doesn't quite seem to work either way. I have also used Image optimisation and as per NextJs suggestion added the sharp package too.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the 'waterfall' of async data fetches, the main thread waits until all of them are resolved:

```
const cartList = await getCartList({}, token, cookie);
  const contact_us = await getContactUs({}, token, cookie);
  const contact_number = await getContactNumber({}, token, cookie);
  let searchProducts = await getProductBySearch({}, token, cookie);
  let coupons = await getCoupons({}, token, cookie);
  let userdetails = await getUser({}, token, cookie);
  const recent = await getRecentViews({}, token, cookie);
```

There are 2 recommended data fetching solutions for Next.js:

- `useEffect()` hook
- `SWR` library from the creators of Next.js.

Also I'd recommend split this to many components and fetch data inside each component independently.

#### useEffect() hook data fetching

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
 
function Profile() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/profile-data')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])
 
  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>
  if (!data) return <p>No profile data</p>
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <p>{data.bio}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### SWR library for data fetching

```js
import useSWR from 'swr'
 
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())
 
function Profile() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/profile-data', fetcher)
 
  if (error) return <div>Failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <p>{data.bio}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can read more on this in the [official documentation of Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/client-side)